# Request add header before sending

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to add a parameter to the header of my request before sending it without adding it manually every time.
For example, if I have a fast api project, I can create a middleware. This middleware will be executed directly after a request comes in and before the mapped function is called.
Does someone know how to have something like that for outgoing requests with the requests library?

Comment: at a high level you just wrap requests.request with your own function that has the same signature, and then you just modify the headers parameter before sending on to requests.request.  anything more detailed would require some example code to work with

Comment: could you give an example how to wrap the function? example code is just simple response = requests.post("www.google.de", json="{"name":"Gerry"}")

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own function that calls requests and adds whatever header(s) you want added every time:

```
import requests

def post(url, json):
    headers = {'My Header': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'}
    return requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=json)

post(url="www.google.de", json={"name":"Gerry"})
```

Comment: This would work but then I had to do the same for get and also use this function instead of the function of the requests library. Im looking for something to inject my additional code between calling the requests.post() and the final execution. Maybe there is nothing like a middleware for requests but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: requests.request takes method as a parameter, so you could have a single wrapper work for both get and post (and put, etc).  I guess we have different senses on what "elegant" means here :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a override class to wrap requests module. Look at my use case to wrap a Authorization token:

```
import requests
from functools import partial

class HTTPSession:
  def __init__(self, headers):
    self.http_client = requests
    self.headers = headers

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return partial(self.override, name)

  def override(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(self.http_client, method)(*args, **kwargs, headers=self.headers)

http_session = HTTPSession({'Authorization': 'Bearer 123456'})
req = http_session.post('https://webhook.site/90fec2a5-17d2-41b4-b4c6-28ef81b55883')
req.request.headers['Authorization'] # 'Bearer 123456'
```